# OpenLayers 2.12+ and JQueryUI draggable panel

Tags: jquery-ui, openlayers, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a problem with Openlayers 2.12+ and JQueryUI draggable panel that contains OL tools. The panel locks drag.

CSS:

```
herramientas {
    position: absolute;     top: 15px;  left: 45px;     width: 250px;   height: 35px;   z-index:99999;  cursor: move;
    background: #000000; }
#herramientas div { 
    float: left;
    margin: 5px; }
```

HTML:

```
<body>    
   <div id="mapcontainer" style="width: 650px; height: 500px; position: relative">
    <div id="map" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>

    <div id="herramientas"></div>
   </div>
  </body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var map, layer;
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("#herramientas").draggable({containment: "#mapcontainer"});


        map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map' );
        layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
                                         "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
                                         {layers: 'basic'} );
        map.addLayer(layer);
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();

        nav = new OpenLayers.Control.NavigationHistory();
        map.addControl(nav);
        panel = new OpenLayers.Control.Panel(
            {div: document.getElementById("herramientas")}
        );
        panel.addControls([nav.next, nav.previous]);
        map.addControl(panel);

    });
```

The code demo can see in http://jsfiddle.net/leal33/49bP9/

The same example with OpenLayers 2.11 working perfectly --> http://jsfiddle.net/leal33/49bP9/1

It's a bug of OpenLayers? Any solution?

Thanks